# How does QThread work when an existing thread is executed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qthread

I'm using Pyside and QThread and when a tab is changed, I run a method.

```
self.tabWidget.connect(self.tabWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentChanged(int)"), self.changeTab)
```

In this method, I call start() on my workerThread. In my workerThread I return a signal listAcquired() and i have a listener for that.

```
self.workerThread.connect(self.workerThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("listAcquired()"),self.executeList)
```

The problem here is that when tabs are changed quickly, and workerThread.start() is called twice, the first one seems to go through and the second call seems to stop. Therefore I end up displaying contents from the first tab on the second tab. Why does the second call not go through?